# Pass custom element of an array from an inherited class to main sketch

Tags: c, array, pointer

I'm building a base class that creates color patterns using FastLed's CRGB structure. I use the base class as inheritance for another more specific class that modifies a vector of *colors* (`Pixels[]`) and at some point I want to pass the color of a specific element from my class to the main sketch. But i'm having some issues with it, since the content of **`Pixels[]`** doesn't seem to match what I actually write in there.

Pattern.h:

```
class Pattern
{
    public:
    CRGB PixelAt(int idx);
    CRGB Pixels[6];
}
```

Pattern.cpp:

```
CRGB Pattern::PixelAt(int idx) 
{
  // safety check
  if (idx >= 0 && idx < NumLeds)
  {
    return Pixels[idx];
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.print("Index out of bounds: "); Serial.println(idx);
    return CRGB::Black;
  }
}
```

TestPattern.h:

```
class TestPattern : public Pattern {
    void Tick(unsigned long millis);
}
```

TestPattern.cpp:

```
void TestPattern::Tick(unsigned long millis)
{
    for (int p = 0 ; p < NumLeds ; p++)
    {
      Pixels[p]=CRGB::Blue;
    }
}
```

Main Sketch:

```
for (int p = 0; p < NUM_PATTERNS; p++)
{
  // update pattern
  ledPatterns[p].Tick(millis());

  if (ledPatterns[p].Status == Enabled)
  {
    // sum the values of the pixels
    for (int l = 0; l < NUM_LEDS; l++) {
      leds[l] += ledPatterns[p].PixelAt(l);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm skipping parts of the code to make it easier to read, but I think with this much you should be able to help me make it work. I'm still getting acquainted with C and pointers, which is where I think the problem lies.

So how should I declare and use **`Pixels[]`** so that the Main Sketch, the base class and the inherited class all have consistent information?

Comment: On the face of it that all looks fine. What is the actual problem you are having though? You have gone through and told us what it is supposed to do, but you have forgotten to tell us what actually happens.

Comment: I was not clear when i said "the content of Pixels[] doesn't seem to match what I actually write in there.". I write all the pixels to Blue and when i read them back in the main sketch i get random values.

Comment: I figure out something else that is wrong. I have the Tick function in the parent class, but i actually want every child class to overload Tick with its own implementation, which is not happening. When i call Tick in the Main Sketch (also edited that in the main question since i forgot to put it there), the Tick that is being called is the one from the parent class, not the child class, why is that? I thought by default the child function would be called, and not the parent.

Comment: @LuisFerreira thats usually caused by changing of object copies. Try to add `Pattern(Pattern &) = deleted;` and `Pattern & operator=(const Pattern &) = deleted;` into the Pattern class. And it won't let you copy this object.

Comment: @KIIV you mean add those lines in the Header file? I get this compile error if i past them there in the public section:
"error: invalid pure specifier (only '= 0' is allowed) before ';' token"

Comment: If you want a child member function to override a parent member function the parent member function has to be marked as `virtual`.

Comment: @LuisFerreira About ticks: if you have TestPattern * patterns[N]; and then you assign pointer to child, you have to use `virtual void Tick(unsigned long millis);`  and the same in child class.

Comment: @KIV In the child class you can use `final` to say "this will never be overwritten in a further child" which helps the compiler do a better job of optimizing.

Comment: @Majenko i want the Tick function to override the parent function since different patterns will have different behaviours . And i want the parent class PixelAt function to be used for all childs, since this code doesn't change from pattern to pattern

Comment: @Majenko if you are talking about deleted copy constructor it's basically impossible to override. But, if he's overriding something, it's good idea to add `override` specifier. If it doesn't actually override anything it'll refuse to compile.

Comment: @KIIV I mean in the virtual function. Parent: `virtual void Tick(.....);` - child: `final void Tick(......);`

Comment: @Majenko Or he can make whole child class final:  `struct Child final : public Parent {` and for the methods I think it should be at the end:  `virtual void Tick(...) final override;`

Answer (score 1):

After reading comments i got some more clues where to search and indeed the problem was somewhat in the inheritance and how i was calling the functions. This post helped me [find the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681286/why-is-a-virtual-function-of-child-class-not-called).

I forgot to post the piece of code where i was creating the patterns in the Main Sketch, this is how it was initially:

```
Pattern ledPatterns[NUM_PATTERNS];
ledPatterns[0] = TestPattern(NUM_LEDS, "Test Pattern 1", TestPat, 0, 0);
ledPatterns[1] = TestPattern(NUM_LEDS, "Test Pattern 2", TestPat, 0, 1);

...
ledPatterns[p].Tick(millis());
...
```

When i later called `ledPatterns.Tick` (the function that modifies the values, the function actually being called was the parent and not the child. Thus the unexpected result.

This is how i should have been initializing the patterns, since they are inherited:

```
Pattern* ledPatterns[NUM_PATTERNS];
ledPatterns[0] = new TestPattern(NUM_LEDS, "Test Pattern 1", TestPat, 0, 0);
ledPatterns[1] = new TestPattern(NUM_LEDS, "Test Pattern 2", TestPat, 0, 1);

...
ledPatterns[p]->Tick(millis());
...
```

Sorry for the huge confusion, i thought the problem was in a completely different part of the code